# Is it ok to move a question's text body from below the code into the beginning?

Tags: discussion, edits

Suppose that a question begins with a code sample and after it there is text. Is it ok to pull the text into the beginning so it's visible in the preview (eg. "new questions" page). Code-only preview doesn't seem useful.

Comment: Wow, people actually use those tooltips?

Comment: Not only tooltips, they are visible at least in the "newest" question page.

Comment: Oh yeah, those.

Comment: I do this occasionally when there's something else about the question that needs to be changed too, such as making it less wordy and more to the point.

Comment: I so desperately want to edit this post to rearrange it, but there's only 3 sentences. :)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

[Yes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

> **Introduce the problem before you post any code**
>
> In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you
>   put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're
>   trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from
>   solving it yourself. The first paragraph in your question is the
>   second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and
>   informative as possible.

The Help Center specifically states that's how a good question should be formatted and, as [SurvivalMachine points out in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327796/is-it-ok-to-move-a-questions-text-body-from-below-the-code-into-the-beginning#comment366131_327796), the first few lines of a question are what appear in questions lists (newest, active, search results, etc.).

Folks under 2K rep like myself ought to only do this if there's something else we can edit, but it is an improvement to put an explanation of the problem first. People look at questions they think are interesting and a bunch of unformatted code doesn't tell you anything about whether a question is interesting (or even answerable).

Comment: But if you do that, proofread the text and edit accordingly. If it talks about "the above code", change it to "the below code".

Comment: @pabrams or just remove any indication of direction and just replace it with "I'm doing this" (or similar).